# Android Data Store Preferences does not throw IOException on failed read attempt

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, android-jetpack-datastore

I am building an Android app using Jetpack Compose, I want to make a pin code that is stored in the Data Store preferences. I have created the following data source for it:

```kotlin
val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "mydocument")

val PIN_CODE_KEY = stringPreferencesKey("pin_code")

class PinCodeLocalDataSource @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context
) {
    fun getPinCode(): Flow<List<Int>> {
        Log.d(TAG, "Pin code status collected")
        return context.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Data store mapped")
            val pin: String = preferences[PIN_CODE_KEY] ?: ""
            val intPin: List<Int> = pin.toCharArray().map {
                it.digitToIntOrNull() ?: 0
            }
            intPin
        }.catch { e ->
            Log.e(TAG, "Caught an exception while reading pin: ${e.message}")
        }
    }

    suspend fun setPinCode(newCode: List<Int>) {
        context.dataStore.edit { mutablePreferences ->
            mutablePreferences[PIN_CODE_KEY] = newCode.joinToString("") {
                it.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When viewing the logcat and launching my app, it only displays "Pin code status collected", but no error or anything that would indicate that it caught an error. On error, I want to emit an error state, but I can't do that without catch{}. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried catching the exception downstream, but it didn't succeed either. This is the code for my repository method, it uses a flow builder to first emit the loading state, and after that it maps each next value from the flow as a state:

```kotlin
    fun load(): Flow<Loader<List<Int>>> = flow {
        emit(Loader.Loading)
        dataSource.getPinCode().onEach {
            emit(Loader.Success(it))
        }.catch { e ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading pin code failed.")
            if(e is IOException)
                emit(Loader.Error)
            else
                throw e
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

Comment: Why are you expecting there to be an error? Looks to me like it just doesn't have anything to emit. You are going to have an issue using the `catch` operator twice. The second one in your `load()` function's flow can never be reached because the upstream flow has a `catch` operator that will intercept first.

Comment: In the  JavaDoc for `dataSource.data` it is said that it throws an IOException when there is an error while reading data. Isn't the value missing in the preferences an error? I know that only the first `catch{}` intercepts the exception, this catch is just for testing, I actually want to handle this exception in the repository

Comment: I'm rusty and don't remember if the flow always emits a value for the initial state of the key-value pairs even if none have yet been written. Based on what you're saying, it looks like it does not. But are you sure it isn't simply emitting an empty List? That's what I would expect. There is initially no value in the data, so `pin` is `""`. Following through the logic, your `map` function returns an empty List.

Comment: If the library did consider missing data to be an error, that wouldn't be an IOException. It would be something like InitialValueNotDefinedException or something like that which would be specific to the DataStore library. I highly doubt they would consider that an error. Otherwise, everyone using DataStore would have to have a bunch of boilerplate to avoid exceptions when the project is new and initial values haven't been written yet.

Comment: Yes, the `map{}` just never runs, so I think you are correct about the data store not having anythin to emit. So, I should then first check whether the pin code is present in the data store, and if not, redirect the user to a create pin code screen?

Comment: The docs say that flow throws an `IOException` *"encountered when attempting to read from disk"* - i.e. if the data needs to be read from a file, and that read operation throws for whatever reason, then the exception will be passed on to you. `IOException` is meant for errors reading and writing data on a fundamental level - like Tenfour04 says, a missing value in a data structure isn't a read error, it's just "what you're expecting isn't there" (and for a stored value lookup, that's not usually fatal - exceptions are usually for when things have gone irrecoverably wrong)

Comment: Specifically the docs for `DataStore#data` say *"The flow will always either emit a value or throw an exception encountered when attempting to read from disk"* - that implies collecting that flow will *always* give you your preferences object, or throw an exception if the store couldn't be read. That's not about whether a key exists in the store yet, it's purely about providing access to it - so `dataStore.data.map` should always run (and if it doesn't, that exception isn't a "missing PIN" error). Are you saying you never get `"data store mapped"` in your logs?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was really stuck on that one thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really dumb, but the only thing that was wrong is how I collected the flow. `onEach{}` is not a terminal operator, so, as cactustictacs correctly assumed, the body of the flow never run. Data Store returns an empty value, if it has not been written yet, so I just check for that. The new repository method:

```kotlin
        fun load(): Flow<Loader<List<Int>>> = flow {
        emit(Loader.Loading)
        emitAll(
            dataSource.getPinCode()
                .map {
                    if(it.isNotEmpty())
                        Loader.Success(it)
                    else
                        Loader.Error
                }
                .catch { e ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "Loading pin code failed.")
                    if (e is IOException)
                        emit(Loader.Error)
                    else
                        throw e
                }
        )
    }
```

Here, I used flow builder and `emitAll` to concatenate two flows

Comment: Yes, I already figured out `emitAll` for that. I couldn't find any information on the `+` operator, and it doesn't work in the project

Comment: You’re right, I’m remembering wrong!